# Winforms Tag property with two values at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way I can add values of i and j while creating buttons like this?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9hma.png)

PS. sorry for the screen instead of code, but for some reason it can't be accepted

[code after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOdkP.png)

Comment: As you create a custom text for you button, you can create a custom text string for you tag. It will be up to you to parse that string back to your variables.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do. You may use a Tuple, for example, if that's what you're looking for: `buttons.Tag = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);`. You can use an array: `buttons.Tag = new[] { i, j };`. Or you can do something similar to what you did with the `Name` property if you want to represent them as a string.

Comment: Derive your own class from Button, add as many properties as you like.  Use Build > Build and the new control appears at the top of the toolbox.  Pretty essential feature of Winforms, practice soon.

Comment: It seems you are looking for `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your Class **NewButton** and it's derived from **Windows.Forms.Button** Class as well as use **public int i,j property** for making it to accessible by creating its object and all other property of Button.Use like following Code for buttons

**Inheritance**

```
class NewButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        public int i{get;set;}
        public int j{get;set;}
    }
```

Create in your nested loop and set i and j values instead of 5 and 9

```
        NewButton buttons = new NewButton();
        buttons.Text = "ButtonText";
        buttons.Name = "ButtonName";
        buttons.i = 5;
        buttons.j = 9;
        this.Controls.Add(buttons);//adding control to form
```

Comment: I did just as you said and buttons.i and.j for all buttons are 0

Comment: set i and j values using
buttons.i=i;
buttons.j=j;
inside the loops
It will work

Comment: Ok, I checked it diffrently than before and works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could either create a new struct/class to contain the 2 values or use a tuple.

### Class

```
public class ButtonValues
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public int j { get; set; }
}

Button b = new Button();
b.Tag = new ButtonValues { i = i, j = j };
```

Then to retrieve it:

```
ButtonValues val = currentbutton.Tag as ButtonValues;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{val.i} {val.j}");
```

You can always replace the class with a struct.

### Tuple

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Tag = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
```

Then to retrieve them:

```
Tuple<int, int> vals = currentbutton.Tag as Tuple<int, int>;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{vals.Item1} {vals.Item2}");
```